# CentOS で Java を完全に削除したい

Tags: java, centos

CentOS7　で　Java7　をインストールしていました（yumにて）
Java8　にアップデートしたいため、　yum remove　で上記　Java7　をアンインストールしました。
その後、rpmから　Java8　をインストールしたのですが、　古い　Java7　が完全には消えていないようです。

（なのでとりあえず　alternatives　で　Java８に切り替えました）

alternatives　で見ても　Java7　は存在しますし、Java7に切り替えて実行もできます。
Java7は不要なので完全に消したいのですがどうすればいいでしょうか？

yum　には　Java8　しか表示されません。（上記の通りyumでremoveしたので）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java-1.7.0-openjdk` をインストールした際に同時にインストールされるパッケージ `java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless` もアンインストールする必要があります。

`yum provides`コマンドで、ファイルがどのパッケージに属しているか調べることができます。

```
$ yum provides /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.85-2.6.1.2.el7_1.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

出力の一部:

```
1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.85-2.6.1.2.el7_1.x86_64 : The OpenJDK runtime environment without audio and video support
```

Comment: 同じようにしたらできました！
ありがとうございます

Answer (score 2):

削除した物以外にもJavaのパッケージが有るのでしょう。
Java7に切り替えて実行できるという事なので、その状態でどこにインストールされているか調べます。

```bash
realpath /usr/bin/java
# -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java とかでしょうか
```

その後、インストール場所からそれが所属するパッケージを調べます。
`yum provides` や `rpm -qf` でよいと思いますがファイル名でなく、少し上のディレクトリ（上記の例だと /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64）で検索した方が見つかり易いです。